# Getting the same filename when renaming with wget

Tags: windows-10, download, wget, wsl2

Using Windows 10 and wget to download files from a specific location, [installed and configured WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Once the setup was done, opened and ran the following command

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

Then, ran the following command

```
wget --header='Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-PT;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,es;q=0.4,it;q=0.3,gl;q=0.2,hu;q=0.1' --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" -c "http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P="{1..3}"-"{1..12}"-"{2019,2020}"&variation=PT" -w 1
```

This saves the files in `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\molecoder` with the name `SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=1-1-2020&variation=PT`. If I want them as .xls, currently will need to go one by one and change the end of the file to `.xls` or automatically rename the file to what I want.

If I use

```
wget --header='Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-PT;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,es;q=0.4,it;q=0.3,gl;q=0.2,hu;q=0.1' --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" -c "http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P="{1..3}"-"{1..12}"-"{2019,2020}"&variation=PT" -O {1..3}_{1..12}_{2019,2020}.xls -w 1
```

Then I'll get all the files with the name `1_1_2019.xls`. How can I get that number to actually increase respectively (1_1_2019.xls, 1_1_2020.xls, 1_2_2019.xls, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I think that the example in your post should have been
`1_1_2019.xls, 1_2_2019.xls, 1_3_2019.xls`, which is what I base my answer on.)

This is not possible using `wget` alone, except if you construct a bash-type
script that loops on the files.

I suggest using instead the utility
[youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl).

Youtube-dl supports the `%(autonumber)s` variable with calls such as:

```
youtube-dl -a URL-file -o '-o "%(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

The starting number can be set by the parameter `--autonumber-start NUMBER`
to specify the start value for `%(autonumber)s`, where the default is 1.